# Invoke a Firefox addon using a command

Tags: firefox, plugins

Is it possible to engage an addon using an external command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Chatzilla URL is `chrome://chatzilla/content/chatzilla.xul`. To open just that window and not the browser itself, use the `-chrome` option. `-no-remote` is added to prevent an existing session being used.

The command for just starting Chatzilla becomes:

```
firefox -no-remote -chrome chrome://chatzilla/content/chatzilla.xul
```

If you've multiple profiles, specify the profile name too or the path to the profile:

```
firefox -no-remote -P default -chrome chrome://chatzilla/content/chatzilla.xul
firefox -no-remote -profile /path/to/profile -chrome chrome://chatzilla/content/chatzilla.xul
```

This may work for other add-ons as well, just look in the `[profilefolder]/extensions/*/chrome.manifest` file for possible URLs.

- [Mozilla knowledgebase - Command line arguments](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments)

Comment: So how can find out what `*.xul` is for what addon? Not that I need anything other Chatzilla for now...

Comment: It's often `chrome://[name]/content/[name].xul`, you can check the lines in the `chrome.manifest` file.

Comment: I cam across two issues: first, when opening `irc://` link, it opens a Firefox window, and if Firefox is already running the dialog box saying Firefox is already running, etc appears. Do you know of any solution?

Comment: Hmm, if you're not sharing a Firefox profile, you can remove the `-no-remote` option. Could you test it and report back?

Comment: Behavior is subtly different this time. On first invocation of CZ, Firefox appears along with CZ. While that is running and I try opening another link, a tab on the open Firefox window with link appears and another CZ window. Never new CZ could have multiple windows...

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Forums has a nice [tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=140811) to demonstrate how to run firefox addons such as chatzilla outside the firefox browser - obviously the addon must support this mode of working.

I've taken the liberty of copying the suggested code - but have updated with the latest stable versions.

install for xulrunner:

```
sudo apt-get install xulrunner-1.9.2
```

Get the sources for chatzilla:

```
wget http://chatzilla.rdmsoft.com/xulrunner/download/chatzilla-0.9.86.1-xr.zip
sudo mkdir /opt/xulrunner/chatzilla
sudo unzip -d "/opt/xulrunner/chatzilla" chatzilla-0.9.86.1-xr.zip
rm chatzilla-0.9.86.1-xr.zip
```

Now run the chatzilla app:

```
xulrunner -app "/opt/xulrunner/chatzilla/application.ini"
```

Comment: The repositories do already have a `xulrunner-1.9.2` package. If you've a 64-bit system, the 32-bit binaries from Mozilla cannot even be used.

Comment: And I wouldn't want to decouple Chatzilla from Firefox. But this is a nice solutions for independent addons that's useful outside the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the addon explicitly contains some command, no.

Comment: Contains some command? In my specific case, I want open Chatzilla (it can run without any Firefox window running).

Comment: @Oxwivi have you looked into the addon's folder or tried to find out if they provide a standalone version?

Comment: Nope, I'm totally unfamiliar with how they actually work, hence the question. I'll do as you recommend now.

Comment: Found `chatzilla.jar` - anything I can do with it?

Comment: There's also `chatzilla-service.js`.

Comment: The `chatzilla.jar` file can be extracted using `unzip`, but the extracted components cannot be used directly, it's for internal use.

Comment: I figured it was just that @Oxwivi. Most firefox addons do not contain a command that you can run apart from the browser. Some are packaged with xulrunner by the developer to allow you to run them like that, but most are not, because it is a lot of work.